# append and InsertBefore are acting weird together

Tags: jquery, ajax, append

I'm trying to append new DIV's every second starting from the top of the list instead of adding them at the bottom with AJAX.

This is a part of the code:

```
var item_code = '<div class="content"> SOME CONTENT HERE </div>' 
$("#container_div").append(item_code); 
$('.content').insertBefore('.content');
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container_div"></div>
```

I've tried lots of other variations of this code and they are all working the same strange way. It creates 1-4 items per update and they are not organized at all (some appear on the top of the list and some go to the bottom).

Comment: Looks like an error, `item_code` is a string, and it has no `insertBefore` method

Comment: Which element should `('div:first')` represent? The first child of `div#container_div` ? if so, then your selector is wrong here

Comment: Now it makes even less sense, why would you insert an element before itself, you'd just end up with the same thing ?

Comment: I've edited with another variation I used. Please take a look (same result). I'm not a JS navy so if someone could point me to the answer i will be grateful.

Comment: @adeneo I'm creating a new `.content` div every second and I want the new ones to appear at the top. Have no idea what's wrong here..

Comment: So in your question, `2nd` actually means second, as in time ?

Comment: @adeneo, yeah... that's what code does to my brain.

Comment: So i guess what you want is just `$("#container_div").prepend(item_code); ` then ?

Comment: Doesn't help. I need that the newly created DIV's will appear on top of those already created. `#container_div` is the parent DIV where everything is added. I have a new `.content` DIV with contents added inside of a `#container_div` every second.

Comment: @Ricardo That's what `prepend()` does. It puts the new element at the beginning of the container, instead of at the end.

Comment: You guys rock! Thank you so much.